# Display the values and their indices in a two dimensional array, in order of minimum to maximum?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I enter a (large) number, followed by a smaller number, the larger number displays first. Is there are way to display both values, one time for each value of Minimum and Maximum, in order of Minimum and Maximum with their indices in the array? e.g. "Monkey number 2 ate the least amount of food, 3 on day 2. Monkey number 1 ate the most amount of food, 10 on day 5.

I'm at my wits end ... I've rewritten this so many times but it comes out worse than what I have below.

```
//Find the greatest amount of food eaten, and the least amount of food eaten by a monkey.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
constexpr auto COLUMN = 5;
constexpr auto ROW = 3;


///////////////////////////////////////////////////PROTOTYPE
void foodInput(double monkeyArray[ROW][COLUMN], double userInput);
void foodCalculator(double monkeyArray[ROW][COLUMN]);
void minMaxFoodEatenFinder(double monkeyArray[ROW][COLUMN]);



//////////////////////////////////////////////////PROGRAM START
int main()
{
    //VARIABLES GO HERE
    double monkeyArray[ROW][COLUMN];
    double userInput = 0.0;

    //START FUNCTION HERE
    foodInput(monkeyArray, userInput);
    foodCalculator(monkeyArray);
    minMaxFoodEatenFinder(monkeyArray);

    return 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////FUNCTIONS GO HERE
void foodInput(double monkeyArray[ROW][COLUMN], double userInput) //Handles input into multidimensional array
{

    for (int monkeyNumber = 0; monkeyNumber < ROW; monkeyNumber++)//monkey loop executes
    {
        for (int day = 0; day < COLUMN; day++)//days of the week loop executes 5 times
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the pounds eaten by monkey number " << monkeyNumber + 1 << "\non day " << day + 1 << ": ";
            while (true)
            {
                std::cin >> userInput;
                if (std::cin.fail() || userInput <= 0)
                {
                    std::cin.clear();
                    std::cin.ignore(256, '\n');
                    std::cout << "Enter a non-negative amount: " << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    monkeyArray[monkeyNumber][day] = userInput;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


void foodCalculator(double monkeyArray[ROW][COLUMN])//Averages the amount of food eaten per day
{


    for (int day = 0; day < COLUMN; day++)//for loop to average out the columns
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        double average = 0.0;

        for (int monkeyNumber = 0; monkeyNumber < ROW; monkeyNumber++)//what all three monkeys ate on day #__, average it
        {
            sum = sum + monkeyArray[monkeyNumber][day];
        }

        average = (sum / 3.0);
        std::cout << "The average amount eaten on day " << day + 1 << " is " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << average << " pounds." << std::endl;
    }
}

void minMaxFoodEatenFinder(double monkeyArray[ROW][COLUMN])//Find the biggest number and find the smallest number in the array
{
    int minimumNum = monkeyArray[0][0];
    int maximumNum = monkeyArray[0][0];

    for (int monkeyNumber = 0; monkeyNumber < ROW; monkeyNumber++)
    {

        for (int day = 0; day < COLUMN; day++)
        {

            if (monkeyArray[monkeyNumber][day] > maximumNum)//if you're bigger than the max, you're the new max
            {
                maximumNum = monkeyArray[monkeyNumber][day];
            }
            if (monkeyArray[monkeyNumber][day] < minimumNum)//if you're smaller than the min, you're the new min
            {
                minimumNum = monkeyArray[monkeyNumber][day];
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)//display the monkey number, food amount, and day the food was eaten
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            if (monkeyArray[i][j] == minimumNum)
            {
                std::cout << "Monkey number: " << i + 1 << " ate the least amount of food, \n" << minimumNum << " on day " << j + 1 << std::endl;
            }
            if (monkeyArray[i][j] == maximumNum)
            {
                std::cout << "Monkey number: " << i + 1 << " ate the most amount of food, \n" << maximumNum << " on day " << j + 1 << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use a C-Style array? If not, this can be done in just a couple lines using STL containers.

Comment: Please simplify the example code (c.f. [mcve]). Based on your description, I suspect that `foodInput()` and `foodCalculator()` could be replaced with a hardcoded initalization of `monkeyArray`. In any event, only one of those three functions should be necessary to demonstrate the error you are having. (Kudos, though, on a generalized description.)